# Setting the steering box correctly on a 1967 Chevy C10 pickup

Tags: chevrolet, steering, truck, c10

I’m rebuilding a 1967 Chevy C10 pickup and have replaced the entire front end with new parts. I changed from 6 lug to 5 lug, to new tires/rims to the ball joints, including a new steering box.

The biggest problem is that the steering wheel has close to 1/3 or more steering play. Everyone says that’s normal, no it is not!

I have learned that there is a certain way the steering box needs to be put in, but? Any and all words will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Where is the play in the system? At the steering box itself, or in the linkages? You should be able to look at what the linkages are doing by having someone move the steering wheel back and forth while you examine. Once you figure that out, you'll know what to do. There is an adjustment in the steering box which will take up the slack, if that's where the slop is.

Comment: Check the rag joint also.

Comment: Everything, everything is new. Including the rag joint. The play is in the steering wheel and steering column.  And the adjusting nut on the steering box Has been adjusted and played with and still has bad play. There isn’t any more room to adjust. Someone screwed something up.

Comment: The steering wheel itself will not have any play.  Did you check the u-joint in the steering column for wear?